# How to use Artifactory Retrieve Latest Artifact with different file extensions?

Tags: artifactory

I am using the Artifactory REST API call Retrieve Latest Artifact to download artifacts. I have a unique situation where the repository layout uses a custom extension. The repository is using the layout

```
[org]-[module]/[module]_[baseRev].(compiled-library|library|rext)
```

I have tried using

```
[org]-[module]/[module]_[baseRev].[ext]
```

But this does not recognize files with the .compiled-library extension.

I have noticed when using the Retrieve Latest Artifact changing the order of extensions in the regex .(compiled-library|library|rext) changes what artifacts are found by the Retrieve Latest Artifact call.

For example, using the order shown above, the API call works on any artifact with .compiled-library extensions but returns a 404 error with file not found for the other files. I can then change the regex to .(rext|compiled-library|library) and only the .rext files are found by the request.

I have checked the repository and can see that all artifacts in the repository have a module ID and are being recognized by the repository layout.

Is there something about the regex for the repository layout that is incorrect? Or is Artifactory not properly parsing the regex when retrieving the latest artifact?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find already a solution?